# Soap 1.2 to support text/xml content-type in jaxws

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Is it possible for soap 1.2 to entertain a request that has content-type:text/xml? I have a requirement that without changing the client i would enhance soap service to support 1.2 binding. if there is a way/workaround please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This ia s  mismatch in the client/server bindings, where the message version in the service uses SOAP 1.2 (which expects application/soap+xml) and the version in the client uses SOAP 1.1 (which sends text/xml). WSHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.2, BasicHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.1.

It usually seems to be a wsHttpBinding on one side and a basicHttpBinding on the other.
Do not forget check the bindings-related code too. So if you wrote:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
Be sure that all your app.config files contains

<endpoint address="..."
          binding="basicHttpBinding" ...
not the

<endpoint address="..."
          binding="wsHttpBinding" ...
```

or so.